# Google Cloud Single-Node File Server add another disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, fileserver, zfs

I made a fairly standard deployment of the Single-Node File Server on Google Cloud. It works fine as I can mount the file server's disk from other instances.

However, now I want to add another disk to the same file server. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/single-node-fileserver) says I should use the following command to add another file system:

```
zfs create storagepool_name/file_system_name
```

I tried to run this command on the VM that is acting as the file server, but I get the error that the command zfs is not found.

Now I can probably install zfs myself, but I wonder whether that will somehow collide with whatever the deployment has already set up on the machine.

Is installing and setting up zfs myself a problem? If so, how do I add another disk to the file server?

Comment: zfs is installed on your system. The issue is that the commands are not part of the `PATH` environment variable or you are trying to run the command as the wrong user.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for your comment. I managed to solve this problem myself eventually, but your comment did provide a part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong with my setup of the Single-Node File Server.

First, the default deployment settings seems to choose xfs as the default file system instead of zfs. The file server I had was using xfs, as can be seen in the metadata of the instance itself.

Secondly, as user [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) commented in my question, even with zfs selected as the file system, only the root user has its PATH variable set-up properly to be able to directly use the zfs command.